# Radio button checked not working in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble getting the "checked" attribute to work on a radio button in React. Note that the class attribute correctly updates to "selected" when I click the radio button, so the "activeRating.time_felt_right === false" check is working.

```
<input type="radio" value="false"
  id={`time_felt_right_${activeRating.id}_false`}
  checked={activeRating.time_felt_right === false}
  className={activeRating.time_felt_right === false ? 'selected' : null}
  onChange={e => {
      console.log('false');
      e.preventDefault()
      updateActiveRating({ time_felt_right: false })
    }
  }
/>
```

activeRating is provided by Redux's mapStateToProps. updateActiveRating is defined as follows:

```
const mapDipsatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateActiveRating (rating) {
    dispatch(updateActiveRatingAction(rating));
  },
});
```

Comment: try providing a  "name" attribute for checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the idea @DayanMorenoLeon. I added a name, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is `activeRating` and what is the source of `updateActiveRating`? Please add all relevant code

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay. Updated!

Comment: The error could be anywhere. You might not be returning a new object in your store, so redux won't update. You might not be reading it right in the render function. You're also always dispatching `false` hard coded, which could be the issue.

Comment: @AndyRay except that the className updates properly, and checked uses the same model

Comment: that `e.preventDefault()` might be the culprit... try removing that one

Comment: @jpdelatorre That was it. Thank you. I'd stupidly copy-and-pasted from a link, which needed prevent default to avoid a page refresh, but it broke it here. If you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you remove the `e.preventDefault()` it should work